# Starting a Process as a Different User in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, process

I have an ASP.NET MVC web app and in one of the controller actions I want to start process (exe file). The process needs to run under a domain user, because it accesses other resources on the domain. This can either be a single hard coded user, or the user that is currently on the web page. The web.config is using Windows authentication.

I have tried turning impersonation on and tried turning impersonation on specifying a specific user. Both of these scenarios will cause permission issues.

I have also tried starting the process as a specific domain/user/password, but this will give me an error "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password". I'm positive that the username/password is correct, and doing a "runas" works fine.

I'm not even sure of the "correct" way to do this. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is to not launch a process from a Web app. Use something like [MSMQ in WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789048.aspx) instead.

Comment: Ok, so shove some info into MSMQ, then pull it out with a service that is running as a user that can handle this... I could just create a WCF service to do the work that the exe is currently doing then. I was hoping to not have to have a whole other service to do this. Maybe that's the best way though.

Comment: It shouldn't be too difficult to do. If you have Windows server 2008 you could host the service using WAS- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734677.aspx. Writing a Windows service isn't really that much more work though- it took me less than 10 minutes to convert a console WCF service into a Windows Service (I only have Windows 2003).

Comment: I'm going to move my exe code into a WCF service that's started as a domain user and see if that works better.

Comment: Doing it as a WCF service hosted in a Windows service worked great. I just set the Windows service startup user as the domain account.